# Метод для запроса информации из базы на C#

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Есть у меня программа, которой я могу подключаться к БД SQL, запускать процедуру на SQL сервере с параметрами, и получать ответ. Ответ это обычно список из одного столбца и нескольких строк.

```
string ConString = "Server=servname;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;"; //строка подключения к БД с использованием Windows авторизации
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = string.Format(@"DECLARE   @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Match] 
    @FN_Client = N'{0}',
    @LN_Client = N'{1}',
    @MN_Сlient = N'{2}' 
", fn, sn, mn);//текст запроса
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```

Хочу создать класс, и метод, чтобы не плодить много кода. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно засунуть в метод мой код, чтобы на выходе получить список?

Comment: Используйте List<string>, у него есть метод Add, и... возможно ToArray понравится.

Comment: Хотите написать свою ORM? :)

Comment: @Mirdin Что такое ORM?

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Не используйте `String.Format` для построения SQL-запросов, это небезопасно. Вместо этого, используйте параметры.
- Для вызова хранимой процедуры не обязательно составлять запрос EXEC вручную, можно установить тип запроса `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, тогда достаточно написать имя процедуры

Метод для вызова процедуры, возвращающей список строковых значений, можно реализовать как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public static IEnumerable<string> ExecuteProcedure(string sql, params SqlParameter[] args)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_str);
    con.Open();

    using (con)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;                
        cmd.Connection = con;
        for(int i=0;i<args.Length;i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add( args[i]);                    
        }

        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        using (rd)
        {
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              dt.Load(rd);

              var results = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              select myRow[0].ToString();
              return results;
        }
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
var collection = ExecuteProcedure("dbo.[Match]", 
    new SqlParameter("FN_Client", fn), 
    new SqlParameter("LN_Client ", ln),
    new SqlParameter("MN_Сlient ",mn));

foreach (var s in collection ) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример. Пока я не особо его понял, т.к. только учусь. Но у меня все получилось, и это облегчило мне задачу. Намного. Но есть один вопрос. Почему не безопасно использовать String.Format для запуска SQL запросов.

Comment: @AndreySherman При использовании String.Format, если  значение параметра будет содержать служебные команды SQL, они потенциально могут быть выполнены сервером БД. При использовании SqlParameter они будут автоматически экранированы и обработаны как текст. Это главным образом представляет опасность для строковых параметров, вводимых пользователем, но есть и другие случаи (см. например https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/), поэтому хорошей практикой стало всегда использовать SqlParameter при работе с запросами.

Comment: Спасибо большое.